# Does Warding Bond carry over damage type?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-types

The [*warding bond*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-bond) spell description states:

> While the target is within 60 feet of you, it gains a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws, and it has resistance to all damage. Also, each time it takes damage, you take the same amount of damage.

If you cast the spell on another creature and then that creature is damaged, what type is the damage you take? If the target receives 12 slashing damage, do you get 6 slashing damage, or just 6 (untyped) damage?

Comment: Related [question and answer is here,](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62821/22566) I am not sure if this is a dupe or not.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I read that one before creating this question, it does not really mention damage _type_

Comment: @Miniman's answer discusses damage type, and the lack of specificity, but I concur with your "it's not a dupe" point.  VtC removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Damage is **never** "untyped":

> Different attacks, damaging spells, and other harmful 
>   effects deal different types of damage. (p. 75 Basic Rules)

[Jeremy Crawford confirmed this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/808833377621057536):

> All damage has a type. #DnD

Since it cannot be "untyped" and there is no basis for assuming the type would change, it is the type(s) of the original damage.

---

The damage types are Acid, Bludgeoning, Cold, Fire, Force, Lightning, Necrotic, Piercing, Poison, Psychic, Radiant, Slashing, and Thunder. (p. 75 Basic Rules)

Comment: This is an important distinction from previous editions, notably 3.5 and PFRPG, which *did* have untyped damage.

Comment: DaleM - I added page references and the types.  Hope that's OK with you.  Taking your approach makes sense of [J. Crawford's text](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/11/04/warding-bond/) that is cited in the other answer.

Comment: This answers it way better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/525748369361485824) from Jeremy Crawford *implies* that the type carries over for purposes of resistance, if the resistance would still take effect. Though, even it isn't entirely clear on the matter.

> If the cleric has resistance, nothing in the rules says it doesn't work.

While Jeremy's posts are not official rulings any longer, they are his and his team's intention on how they intended the rule to work. Moreover, in this particular case he is even pointing out that the rules as written don't prevent resistance from working.

The stronger argument, of course, is that there is no such thing as untyped damage, which Dale makes in his answer.

Comment: Note that [Crawford's tweets are no longer considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/33569). Your answer would be improved by citing the relevant rules and addressing whether they support Crawford's ruling/your answer.

Answer (score 2):

RAW? I can't seem to find anything definitive. Looking at the spell, and the nature of it, I assume you take the same type of damage. Again, I don't see anything in the rules.

This, like every ambiguity, comes down to the DM.

Thematically, you have this magical bond and as your target/ally takes a sword across the face, you feel the slash across your face as well.

The only case I could make for it being just straight damage (other than the DM just wants that) is that in the spell, it says:

> While the target is within 60 feet of you, it gains a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws, and it has resistance to all damage.

As for resistance, The target resists the damage type because of the spell. You are hit with half of that damage. Resistances don't stack (see other answers and PHB 197), but since this is brand new damage to you, you have not resisted it yet. If you are resistant to that type, you take 1/4 of the original total. If you are immune to it, you take zero.

**Example**

> 1. Ogre hits your ally with Warding Bond for 32 bludgeoning damage.
> 2. Your ally (due to the spell) is resistant to that damage; he takes 16 bludgeoning damage.
> 3. You take the same amount of damage, 16 bludgeoning damage.
>    Since you are a barbarian cleric, you are resistant to that damage while raging. You cast the spell then raged, thus are resistant. You take 8 bludgeoning damage.

Comment: I am not sure if resistance stacks (pretty sure that it doesn't) but I think you are right since the second party only sees the "half damage" and then gets resistance to that.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Going by the following, it seems that would stack: "[Does the caster's resistance, vulnerability or immunity affect damage from Warding Bond?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101846)"

Comment: @Medix2 you can't stack resistance, that's a rule. So if the barbarian is the one being warding bonded,  and is raging, the resistance does not stack.  If the one being warded isn't a raging barbarian, or otherwise have resistance, then the damage comes to the cleric / barbarian 'unmodifed' and is reduced by that resistance, since the cleric does not get resistance from the warding bond spell. One of my first questions here on this site was warding bond, might want to check out the order of operations in that.

Comment: I would definitely just go with whatever @korvinStarmast said. I think a lot of times I end up having to make snap decisions in games, and that's fine, I usually err on the side of giving the player grace. I want to make sure they're having fun. Part of fun though is making sure there is a real sense of danger. Anyway I digress...