# What type of damage does Bond of Mutual Suffering deal to the attacker?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, damage-types

The **Bond of Mutual Suffering** feature of the Blood Magic Wizard from *Tal’dorei Campaign Setting: Reborn* says:

> At 6th level, when a creature you can see hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to bind your vitality to the attacker and force them to share your pain. The attacker takes damage equal to the damage you took.

The *Player's Handbook*, Ch. 9, says:

> Different attacks, damaging spells, and other harmful effects deal different types of damage. Damage types have no rules of their own, but other rules, such as damage resistance, rely on the types.

What type of damage does this feature do to the attacker? Is it type-less damage? Is it the same damage type as the triggering attack deals? Is it something else entirely?

Comment: Highly related, possible duplicate: [Does Warding Bond carry over damage type?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91688/23547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The DM must assign the type

There generally is no untyped damage in 5e, PHB, p. 195

> Different attacks, damaging spells, and other harmful effects deal different types of damage. Damage types have no rules of their own, but other rules, such as damage resistance, rely on the types.
> The damage types follow, with examples to help a **DM assign a damage type to a new effect**.

So either this would be necrotic damage like that of other blood magic features or the same type of damage as the original damage you took. I’d do the latter, but as the feature does not say, this will be up to your DM to resolve.